# pentaho regex to exclude files with .gz extension and include starting with particular string

Tags: regex, pentaho

I'm trying to access files with pattern

requests_2012-07-19

requests_2012-07-20

requests_2012-07-21

and exclude

requests_2012-07-19.gz

requests_2012-07-20.gz

requests_2012-07-21.gz

Below is the regex I came up with

```
^requests_[0-9-]{10}[^\.gz]$

^requests_[0-9-]{10} // for name of file , this works

[^\.gz]$  // for extension of file, this doesn't work
```

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: What's wrong with your expressions? They match and exclude what you indicated, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/nT0egI/1)

Comment: Use `^requests_[0-9-]{10}(?!.*\.gz$)`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness i tried at http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#experiment , it's not working

Comment: This is a good use case of [negative lookaheads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your suggestion worked :), thanks !

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira Thanks for the reference, precisely my use case !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^requests_[0-9-]{10}(?!.*\.gz$)
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2ntlFE/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `requests_` - a literal substring
- `[0-9-]{10}`  - 10 digits
- `(?!.*\.gz$)` - after any 0 chars as many as possible, there cannot be `.gz` at the end of the string.